# Show input values on other input

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a verification code form, and I want to show entered number on yellow input, but the problem is when you enter 4 numbers then enter new numbers or update old numbers yellow input not updated, and I want to show number on yellow input only if all 4 inputs are has value, if not, clear yellow input.

```js
var code = [];
$('.verf-code input').keyup(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  var val = $(this).val();

  $(this).each(function() {
    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
      $(this).next('input').select().focus();
      code.push(val);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (code.length <= 4) {
    $('.verification-code').val(code.join(''));
   
  } else {
    code = [];
  }

});
```

```css
.verification-code {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="verf-code"><input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" /></div>

<input type="text" class="verification-code">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `data-id` attribute to keep track of which input has a value.

Then I'd filter the `code` array to remove any empty values, and use that to determine if your verification input should have a value:

```js
var code = [];
$('.verf-code input').keyup(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  var val = $(this).val();

  
  code[$(this).attr("data-id")] = $(this).val();
  
  $(this).each(function(index) {
    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
      $(this).next('input').select().focus();
      
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    
  });
  
    var filtered = code.filter(function (el) {
    return el != "";
  });
  
  if (filtered.length == 4) {
    $('.verification-code').val(code.join(''));
   } else {
   $('.verification-code').val('');
   }
    
});
```

```css
.verification-code {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="verf-code">
  <input data-id="0" class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" />
  <input data-id="1" class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" />
  <input data-id="2" class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" />
  <input data-id="3" class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" />
</div>

<input type="text" class="verification-code">
```

Comment: This code allows letters - it does not advance but allows them

Answer (score 1):

```js
var code = [];
$('.verf-code input').on("input", function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.match(/\d/) || "";
  if (this.value.length === 1) {
    $(this).next('input').select().focus();
    code[$(this).index()] = this.value
    const vc = code.join('')
    $('.verification-code').val(vc.length === 4 ? vc : '');
  }
});
```

```css
.verification-code {
  background: yellow;
  width: 72px;
}

.verf-code {
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="verf-code">
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" pattern="\d" tabindex="1" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" pattern="\d" tabindex="2" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" pattern="\d" tabindex="3" />
  <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" pattern="\d" tabindex="4" />

  <input type="text" class="verification-code" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; Almost, but I don't want use type number, because arrows, and don't want to struggle with webkit appearance or etc.. arrows make my UI ugly. and also can we do something about, when input getting empty or empty, yellow input clear? (last sentence in my question)

Comment: @tourtravel I made a new version that does not allow anything but numbers

Comment: @tourtravel I think this code is more elegant and allows the user to tab backwards to change the numbers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra loop (`each`) in your `keyup` event. You need to update  `code` array in each position I use `index` to do that.

Here is working sample:

```js
var code = [];
$('.verf-code input').keyup(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    var val;

    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
        val = $(this).val();
    }
    else
        val = "-1";
    $(this).next('input').select().focus();
    code[$(this).index()] = (val);
    if (code.length == 4 && !code.includes("-1"))
        $('.verification-code').val(code.join(''));
    else
        $('.verification-code').val('');
});
```

```css
.verification-code {
     background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="verf-code">
    <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" />
    <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" />
    <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" />
    <input class="afc-form__item__input" name="verf" type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" />
</div>

<input type="text" class="verification-code">
```

Comment: Hmm, Thanks, just one thing, when you clear one input, can clear yellow input ? I just want to show code when all 4 inputs are filled up. already when you clear one input, it return zero on yellow one

Comment: @tourtravel Yes I updated the answer based on your comment. please check that. now if you clear one input it clears the yellow value

Comment: @tourtravel note that you don't need extra loop for that. now you are using unnecessary loop!

Comment: You cannot back-tab in this code